# Where should I ask about how to drive safely?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about safely driving a car. Where should I ask? It is not related to maintenance and only indirectly related to laws, so Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair and Law are probably not the best choices.

Comment: Ask a driving instructor I imagine.

Comment: Besides what an instructor teaches you, a lot of safety is going to be dependant on forming good habits and training your reflexes. Get practice and assume that for the first three years you'll still be a "beginner".

Comment: Interpretation of foreign (to you) signage might be ok on Travel. General safe driving does not have a SE home that I have seen.

Comment: Your local Department of Motor Vehicles (or whatever the equivalent is where you live) would have resources on safe driving.